# toJSON not working

Tags: jquery, json, cookies

I have the following piece of code and would like to know how to make it work.

```
that.clear = function() {
        setCookie(cookieName, [].toJSON(), "/", document.domain, false,
                cookieLifeHours);
        that.renderPopup();
    };
```

I have tried including `jquery.json.js?ver=2.5.1` but it has not made any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what's `toJSON`, but you can use the native implementation - [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
JSON.stringify([]) // "[]"
```

But, don't know what you're trying to do by encoding an empty array as JSON.